# reading a csv file and splitting the matrix

Tags: matlab, csv, matrix

I am new to MATLAB. I have a .csv that is 1001 x 783. The .csv does have headers for each column and the first column is the label.

How do I read the .csv, and specific that the first row is the header. Then, turn it into a matrix. Once in matrix, I want to make 2 matrices from the original. A label matrix that is the first column of the original, and a data matrix that has the 2 column to the end, from the original matrix.

How can I do this?

So far this is what I have:

```
dataFile = importdata('example1.csv', headers = TRUE);
label = dataFile(1:end,1:end);
X = dataFile(2:end, 2:end)
```

For example:
example.csv looks like this

```
label dog1 dog2 dog3 dog4 dog5
true   1     1     2    1   2
false  2     2     1    2   1 
true   1     1     2    1   2
false  2     2     1    2   1
```

label matrix:

```
label 
true   
false  
true   
false
```

X matrix:

```
  dog1 dog2 dog3 dog4 dog5
    1     1     2    1   2
    2     2     1    2   1 
    1     1     2    1   2
    2     2     1    2   1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `readtable`

```
dataFile = readtable('example1.csv', headers = TRUE);
label = dataFile.label;
X = table2array(dataFile(2:end, 2:end))
```